# Contradictory input/output pairs when training neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I think this question can probably be generalized away from neural networks, bu there goes: How should we handle possibly contradictory data? Suppose the neural networks maps n-bit strings to a bit. What if our training data contains something like

```
01101 -> 0
01101 -> 1
```

What is the effect of something like this? Should both instances be deleted as training samples?

or

How should we classify data that is not necessarily deterministic?

Answer (score 3):

The Neural Network will handle this on its own. Depending on the number of instances of the contradictory data the Neural Network will iterate over the values and the eta will change the weights in the direction represented in the data. The net effect will be the majority of instances of the data will have the heaviest impact on the Neural Networks neurons.

Just leave them in, and you will get the "most probable" solution.

Comment: I second to this comment: just leave as it is. If you are really concerned about this, just go through the dataset and see whether there is an issue with your training data labeling. Typically it is good *never* modify the data without *really* good reason. In other words, the cause should be fixed not the outcome of the process which generated the training data.

Answer (score 1):

Real world datasets are rarely deterministic. In the example you've provided above your neural network will learn that when it sees 01101 there will be a 50% probability of 0 and a 50% probability of 1. Deleting the records will make your neural network overconfident, assuming the records were not accidentally mislabeled by whomever gathered the dataset.